# ConstructorExpression create querydsl

Tags: querydsl

I am trying to use `ConstructorExpression.create(RoleDto.class, role.id, BooleanTemplate.FALSE)` in my query.  It is throwing `wrong number of arguments` exception.

Query:

```
    JPAQuery roleQuery = new JPAQuery(em);
List<RoleDto> tupples = roleQuery
    .from(role)
    .where(role.techSupport.isFalse())
    .distinct()
    .list(ConstructorExpression.create(RoleDto.class, role.id, BooleanTemplate.FALSE));
```

RoleDto class:

```
public class RoleDto {

private String roleId;
private boolean bpmRole = false;

public RoleDto(Long roleId, Boolean bpmRole) {
    this.roleId = roleId+"";        
    this.bpmRole = bpmRole.booleanValue();
}

public String getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}
```

}

Also, is there an easy of converting role.id from long to string.